# How to get letters from forloop.counter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have loop in template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="item">
        {{ forloop.counter }}) {{ item.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and I want to display forloop.counter as letters (a,b,c,d,e...) but not using ul->li tags, only forloop.counter. How to do it?

Comment: Have you considered using the cycle template tag? {% cycle 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' %}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could make a custom filter:

```
@register.filter
def to_char(value):
    return chr(98-value)
```

and then in your template:

```
{{forloop.counter|to_char}}
```

Comment: should it not be "chr(96+value)"

Comment: How we declare the custom filter and where?